# Can't close Neotree window

Tags: window

When I try to close the neotree window (`SPC w d` with spacemacs) it just says

> Only one window other than neotree left. Won't close.

It's true that I only have one window other than neotree but what if I want to make it fullscreen ?

Comment: That message can only appear if `neo-dont-be-alone` is `t`.  Check that variable value with `M-x describe-variable RET neo-dont-be-alone RET` and see if it is `t`.  If it is, then change it to the default of `nil` with `(setq neo-dont-be-alone nil)` or figure out where you changed the default which would have been `nil`.  See beginning at line 781 in the source code:  https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/blob/dev/neotree.el#L781

Comment: @lawlist I believe that can be a very fine answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the value for the variable `neo-dont-be-alone` is non-nil (e.g., `t` or some other symbol such as `'foo`), the function `delete-window` (which has been `advice` by the `neotree` library) has check to see whether the `neotree` window would be the only remaining window.

The default value for `neo-dont-be-alone` is `nil`, so the original poster has changed it somewhere along the way.  To restore the default value, either evaluate `(setq neo-dont-be-alone nil)` or find the modification of default behavior within the user-configuration files and remove it (or comment it out).

Here is a link to line 781 of `neotree.el` in the Github repository in the event anyone is interested in seeing the `advice` of `delete-window`:  https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/blob/dev/neotree.el#L781